Custom Post Type and ACF fields not displaying on front page in WordPress
I'm trying to display a Custom Post Type (CPT) called 'affichage_produit' on the front page of my WordPress site. Each 'affichage_produit' post has an Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) 'Post Object' field linking it to a WooCommerce product, and a 'Text Area' field for key points.
I've added the following code to my front-page.php file to query the 'affichage_produit' posts and display the product data and key points:
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'affichage_produit',
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($query->have_posts()) {
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        $product_id = get_field('associated_product');
        $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
        $points_forts = get_field('points_forts');
        // Display the product data and key points here
        if ($product) {
            echo '<h2>' . $product->get_name() . '</h2>';
            echo '<p>Price: ' . wc_price($product->get_price()) . '</p>';
            echo '<p>Points Forts: ' . $points_forts . '</p>';
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
?>

However, nothing is being displayed on the front page. I've confirmed that I have 'affichage_produit' posts and that they have the 'associated_product' and 'points_forts' fields set.
Any ideas why the 'affichage_produit' posts and their associated data are not being displayed?
I've also enabled WP_DEBUG but I'm not seeing any PHP errors.

Do a bit of basic debugging first of all then, to figure out where exactly it goes wrong ... var_dump($query->have_posts()), directly after you made the query, to verify your query got any posts to begin with. If that's the case, check what $product_id = get_field('associated_product'); resulted in, next.

@CBroe thank you so much for helping me out, i just dicovered the problem thanks to you. i will remember to proceed like that in the future.

to retrieve acf field value from a post page, we should pass post_id in the get_filed function like get_filed('associated_product, post_id);

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'affichage_produit',
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($query->have_posts()) {
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();

        // Get the current post ID
        $post_id = get_the_ID();

        // Get the associated product ID from the current 'affichage_produit' post
        $product_id = get_field('associated_product', $post_id);

        // Ensure we have a valid product ID before proceeding
        if ($product_id) {
            // Get the product object using the product ID
            $product = wc_get_product($product_id);

            // Get the 'points_forts' field value associated with the product
            $points_forts = get_field('points_forts', $post_id);

            // Display the product data and key points
            if ($product) {
                echo '<h2>' . esc_html($product->get_name()) . '</h2>';
                echo '<p>Price: ' . wc_price($product->get_price()) . '</p>';
                echo '<p>Points Forts: ' . esc_html($points_forts) . '</p>';
            }
        }`enter code here`
    }

    // Restore original post data after the custom query
    wp_reset_postdata();
}


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
